# Using pastebin API in VB .Net

Tags: vb.net, api, pastebin

I have a small problem, I've just changed from the public Pastebin API to the new API. I get an invalid api error: Bad API request, invalid api_option

Here is my code:

```
Dim Exposure As Integer = 0
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
        If ComboBox1.Text = "Public" Then
            Exposure = 0
        Else
            Exposure = 1
        End If
        Dim fi As String = "?api_paste_private=" & Exposure & "&api_paste_format=" & ComboBox2.Text & "&api_paste_expire_date=" & ComboBox3.Text & "&api_dev_key=CENSORED" & "&api_paste_code=" & code
        Dim w As New System.Net.WebClient()
        w.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        Dim pd As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fi)
        Dim rd As Byte() = w.UploadData("http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php", "POST", pd)
        Dim r As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rd)
        TextBox6.Text = r
        Return r
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: They say on the API page to use UTF-8 encoding, so I tried and it stil isn't working.                                                              Old code: System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes                                New code: System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes

Answer (score 2):

You must add `api_option=paste` to your request, as seen here: http://pastebin.com/api#2